# How can I host Angular frontend and Laravel backend messenger bot with many users

Tags: laravel, api, cloud, vps, saas

I'm starting a new SaaS, where shop owners can register and make their own Facebook messenger chatbots.

The project consists of:
1- Frontend(Angular): Where shop owners can connect their facebook pages and insert their products to the database/ see customer's orders and update the order's status through Laravel API Backend.
2-Backend(Laravel API): Where the requests are handled from the frontend(shop owners) and facebook messenger (shops customers) and data are stored/retrieved from MySQL database.

So lets say i got 300 shop owners subscribed to my SaaS, and each shop has 300 daily customers that will use the chatbot.

Note*: when a shop X customer sends a message to shop X facebook page, the message is sent to the laravel backend, and it will retrieve the products with its pictures and he can place an order, then the order is sent to Laravel backend and stored in the MySQL Database, and retrieved on the Angular frontend for shop X owner. Each shop has its own customers, showing different products, using the same backend. There will be nearly 300 shops subscribed.

What is the best way to host such an application?
what specifications do I need if i use a VPS? ex: RAM, CPU Cores, Most importantly BANDWIDTH.
If you suggest cloud services like AWS/Heroku, please give me guidance what services should I buy and in which capacity? Dynos/databases....etc
what if there is 5000 simultaneuos requests made at the same time to the Backend, which way of hosting can handle this? 
Should i host the frontend and backend on the same server or seperately?

I'm really lost here and can't understand answers such as "It depends".
I want the server specifications depending on the numbers given, please.

Answer (score 0):

One of your questions.  Should i host the frontend and backend on the same server or seperately?  For the planned volume, use two servers with highest speed connection you can budget.  For MySQL tuning assistance, view my profile.